# SqlCommand SUM(NVL()) issue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

Hello I'm trying to select SUM of all payments but got this exception: nvl is not a recognized function name

with this code:

```
            SqlCommand sc2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(NVL(payments,0)) AS sumcastka FROM kliplat WHERE akce=" + zakce.Text, spojeni);

            spojeni.Open();

            int sumOfPrice = 0;
            object vysledek2 = sc2.ExecuteScalar();
            if (vysledek2 != DBNull.Value)
                sumOfPrice = Convert.ToInt32(vysledek2);
           // int vysledek2 = Convert.ToInt32(sc2.ExecuteScalar());

            spojeni.Close();
```

This should work as when no records are found for column "payments" I would like to get "0" if possible.

Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This should work as when no records are found for column "payments"

No, it will only treat NULL values in the `payments` column as 0.

If no records are found, then `ExecuteScalar` returns `null` (not `DBNull`):

```
SqlCommand sc2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(ISNULL(payments,0)) AS sumcastka FROM kliplat WHERE akce=" + zakce.Text, spojeni);

spojeni.Open();

int sumOfPrice = 0;
object vysledek2 = sc2.ExecuteScalar();
if (vysledek2 != null && vysledek2 != DBNull.Value)
    sumOfPrice = Convert.ToInt32(vysledek2);

spojeni.Close();
```

You should also look into using `SqlParameter`s instead of concatenating strings, but that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

`NVL()` is an oracle-specific function. You can use the ANSI `COALSECE` function to perform the same task. The benefit of `COALESCE` is that it takes more than two parameters, and picks the first non-null value.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server there is a funcation called ISNULL for the purpose. Please find the query below:

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(payments,0)) AS sumcastka FROM kliplat WHERE akce=" + zakce.Text, spojeni
```

Comment: Hello should this return ISNULL only when some of the records are NULL. Will this work even when no records are found? Thanks again.

Comment: You mean when the Payment column is blank for that row?

Comment: Nono, I mean when no records were selected. If you know what I mean.

Comment: I think you are suppose to implement that condition in your code.